# Exception thrown at executeUpdate & DriverManager.getConnection

Tags: java, mysql, database, jconnect

I'm trying to connect to a MYSQL database inside java and insert new data. If I use `jconnector` (jar file) version `5.1.47`, an exception is thrown at `executeUpdate(String s)`. If I use version 8 of the jar file, another exception is thrown at `Connection myCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc...")`.

I am using jdk 1.8.0 (version 8) in both scenarios. No error messages, just exceptions. Here is my code which is inside the main function. I can verify that the database is correct on phpmyadmin (I am using xampp to access it).

```java
try {
    final String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    String databaseP = "1234";

    Connection myCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase","root",databaseP);
    Statement St = myCon.createStatement();
    String sql = "insert into clients (username, password) values ('marco', 'polo')";
    St.executeUpdate(sql);
//            System.out.println("Insert complete!");
//            //ResultSet rs = St.executeQuery("select * from Clients;");
//
////            while(rs.next()){
////                System.out.println(rs.getString(""));
////            }
    St.close();
    myCon.close();
}
catch(SQLException e){
    System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
}
```

In case of exception thrown at `Connection myCon`: error code is 0, stacktrace is `[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1574691`

In case of exception thrown at `executeUpdate(sql)`: error code is 1364, stacktrace is `[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@b48321`

Comment: Print the exception itself, not just the error code: `e.printStackTrace(System.out);`. You're missing vital information.

Comment: Replace this line of your code: `System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());` with this line: `e.printStackTrace()`. Then run the code and post the stack trace.